# What is the equivalence in Python 3 of letters in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 2 you get

```
>>> from string import *
>>> letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

But in Python 3, you get

```
>>> from string import *
>>> letters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'letters' is not defined
```

It's not defined, whereas `digits` and `whitespace` are.

What is the equivalence of `letters` from the string module in Python 3?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try using: `string.ascii_letters` instead of just `letters`, here.

More information here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#string-constants

---

**Update:**

As @wim noted in the [previously posted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561432/what-is-the-equivalence-in-python-3-of-letters-in-python-2/9561448#comment91042348_9561448), this suggestion to use `string.ascii_letters` in Python 3 is not equivalent to the `letters` in Python 2. Like wim noted, `string.ascii_letters` [is not locale-dependent](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) while `letters` [is locale-dependent](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.18/library/string.html?highlight=letters#string.letters).

I hope this suggestion can still be helpful, though, but wanted to include the feedback from @wim and the docs.

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc: Note that that only will work if you only even encounter English text.

Comment: For me I had to remove the `string.` part. simply using `ascii_letters` works in my case on python 3.6

Comment: –1 This is *not* equivalent. **The specific value of `string.letters` is locale-dependent**, and `string.ascii_letters` is not.

Comment: ```AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'letters'```