# How to get the current locale's alphabet in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, locale

In Python 2 you could do the following to get the current locale's character set:

```
import string
print string.letters
```

However, in Python 3 the string module's locale-dependent constants (e.g. `string.letters`, `string.lowercase`, `string.uppercase`, etc.) were removed.

How can I get the current locale's character set using Python 3?

Comment: This question was suggested as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561432/what-is-the-equivalence-in-python-3-of-letters-in-python-2 However, as the name suggests, `ascii_letters` returns the ascii characters (a-Z), not the characters of the currently defined locale

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  +1

Comment: My guess is the functionality was removed because it had issues and was an oversimplification in the first place. You might have to try a different approach such as looking at [`unicodedata.category`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category) instead.

Comment: @wim I don't think it can be done with the standard library. `unicodedata.category` doesn't give detailed locale information. `re` has [locale-aware](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.LOCALE) alpha testing with `\w`, etc but it only works on 8-bit locales and "The use of this flag is discouraged as the locale mechanism is very unreliable".

Comment: Unicode CLDR defines [exemplar characters](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/by_type/core_data.alphabetic_information.main.html) for each locale, which seems to be what you want.  Unfortunately, I currently can't find the file that these charts are derived from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the [exemplar characters](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/by_type/core_data.alphabetic_information.main.html) for each locale using the [pyicu](https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu) module:

```
import locale
from icu import LocaleData

default, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()
languages = [default] + ['en_US', 'fr_FR', 'es_ES']

for language in languages:
    data = LocaleData(language)
    alphabet = data.getExemplarSet()
    print(language, alphabet)
```

**Output**

```
pt_BR [a-zà-ãçéêíò-õú]
en_US [a-z]
fr_FR [a-zàâæ-ëîïôùûüÿœ]
es_ES [a-záéíñóúü]
```

To get the current locale is enough to do:

```
default, _ = locale.getdefaultlocale()
data = LocaleData(default)
alphabet = data.getExemplarSet()
print(default, alphabet)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @Dani Mesejo - do you have any solution for Windows and Python 3.11? Installation by `pip` doesn't work and the only link to `PyICU` wheels (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu) no longer works as well.