# Alphabet range in Python

Tags: python, string, list, alphabet

How do I create a list of alphabet characters, without doing it manually like this?

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ..., 'z']
```

Comment: @CharlieParker No, from the beginning I made sure my answer would work on Python 3 as well as Python 2 at the same time, because i used `string.ascii_lowercase` (available on both) and not `string.lowercase` (only on py2)

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927114/is-it-possible-to-make-a-letter-range-in-python (which itself also seems to be a dupe)

Comment: @hkBst Seems the difference is that those questions are asking for a subset range of letters, while this one requests the entire alphabet (which makes the answer more specific)

Answer (score 1231, accepted):

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> list(string.ascii_lowercase)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

---

Alternatively, using `range`:

```
>>> list(map(chr, range(97, 123)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Or equivalently:

```
>>> list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

---

Other helpful `string` module features:

```
>>> help(string)
....
DATA
    ascii_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    ascii_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    digits = '0123456789'
    hexdigits = '0123456789abcdefABCDEF'
    octdigits = '01234567'
    printable = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
    punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
    whitespace = ' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I make it to reverse order?

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase[::-1]`

Comment: The explicit list(...) on the result of map(...) is superfluous since map already returns a list

Comment: @haavee Actually no in Python 3 `map` doesn't return a `list`

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do the same for a specific locale, i.e. get the spanish, turkish, etc. alphabets

Comment: @Gonzalo maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045659/how-to-get-the-current-locales-alphabet-in-python-3

Comment: A few handy tricks in here, ie. `chr()`, `ord()`, and `string.ascii_lowercase` / `string.ascii_uppercase`; all useful for interviews

Answer (score 170):

```
[chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
```

Comment: I got: [chr(alpha+97) for alpha in range(0,27)] but this is much more intuitive. Doesn't require remembering that ascii of a is 97

Comment: @MoeChughtai I don't understand how is this more succinct than `string.ascii_lowercase`

Comment: Also: `chrange = lambda s: "".join(map(chr, range(*map(ord, s))) + [c[1]])`. Usage: `>>> chrange("az") -> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. For a list, just remove `"".join( )`

Comment: @jamylak Maybe MoeChughtai meant that this answer really doesn't drown the solution in lengthy explanations.

Comment: @Fornost `import string` is a lengthy explanation?

Comment: Your answer had many more words than these two, but is more helpful. Helpfulness beats concision, according to the upvotes your answer received.

Comment: @jamylak because there is not string module involved.

Answer (score 62):

In Python 2.7 and 3 you can use this:

```
import string
string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

As @Zaz says:
`string.lowercase` is deprecated and no longer works in Python 3 but `string.ascii_lowercase` works in both

Comment: In Python 3, use string.ascii_lowercase. But this returns a string. In case you need a list, I think, Bg1850 is a neat solution

Comment: As the top answer mentions, 
`string.ascii_letters`, `string.ascii_lowercase`, `string.ascii_uppercase` all work in python 3+.

Comment: @peterb `list(string.ascii_lowercase)`

Answer (score 21):

Here is a simple letter-range implementation:

**Code**

```
def letter_range(start, stop="{", step=1):
    """Yield a range of lowercase letters.""" 
    for ord_ in range(ord(start.lower()), ord(stop.lower()), step):
        yield chr(ord_)
```

**Demo**

```
list(letter_range("a", "f"))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

list(letter_range("a", "f", step=2))
# ['a', 'c', 'e']
```

Comment: Very nice!  Also works with non-Latin characters.  I just tried.

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking to an equivalent of `letters[1:10]` from R, you can use:

```
import string
list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:10])
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the easiest way I can figure out:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
for i in range(97, 123):
    print("{:c}".format(i), end='')
```

So, 97 to 122 are the ASCII number equivalent to 'a' to and 'z'. Notice the lowercase and the need to put 123, since it will not be included).

In print function make sure to set the `{:c}` (character) format, and, in this case, we want it to print it all together not even letting a new line at the end, so `end=''`would do the job.

The result is this:
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Answer (score 4):

Print the Upper and Lower case alphabets in python using a built-in range function

```
def upperCaseAlphabets():
    print("Upper Case Alphabets")
    for i in range(65, 91):
        print(chr(i), end=" ")
    print()

def lowerCaseAlphabets():
    print("Lower Case Alphabets")
    for i in range(97, 123):
        print(chr(i), end=" ")

upperCaseAlphabets();
lowerCaseAlphabets();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I implemented my custom function for letters range generation based on `string.ascii_letters`:

```
from string import ascii_letters


def range_alpha(start_letter, end_letter):
  return ascii_letters[
    ascii_letters.index(start_letter):ascii_letters.index(end_letter) + 1
  ]

print(range_alpha('a', 'z'))
print(range_alpha('A', 'Z'))
print(range_alpha('a', 'Z'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do without import

```
  list = [chr(item) for item in range(ord("a"), ord("z") + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I'll give an answer which is quite flexible. If you have PyICU installed, this can be easily leveraged for this task:

```py
from icu import UnicodeSet
lset = UnicodeSet('[a-z]')
print(list(lset))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
ulset = UnicodeSet('[a-zA-Z]')
print(list(ulset))
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

But you can also use any UnicodeSet patterns in the same way:

```py
uset2 = UnicodeSet('[[:Ll:]&[:Latin:]]')
```

This pattern is an intersection between two sets. The intersection between all lowercase characters and all Latin characters, i.e. all the lowercase Latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want upper/lower case range and also want alternate or with steps then you try below code.

```
def letter_range(start, stop="{", step=1):
    """Yield a range of upper/lowercase letters."""
    if start.isupper():
        if stop == "{":
            stop = "["
        else:
            stop = stop.upper()
        ascii_uppercase = [chr(item) for item in range(ord(start), ord(stop), step)]
        print(ascii_uppercase)

    elif start.islower():
        ascii_lowercase = [chr(item) for item in range(ord(start), ord(stop), step)]
        print(ascii_lowercase)
    else:
        print("Check your input")


letter_range("a", "f", 2)
letter_range("A", "f",)
```

> > > > > > > 

```
['a', 'c', 'e']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```