# Is there a built in list in python or some package that has a list of the alphabet?

Tags: python, enumeration, alphabetical

Is there a built in list in python or some package that has a list of the alphabets? I would like to avoid a system such as

```
alphabets = ('a','b','c',.....)
```

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Comment: because you clearly haven't even googled it.

Comment: The first google result for `python alphabet` is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060899/alphabet-range-python).  The third was the documentation for the `string` module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase):

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> list(ascii_lowercase)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this answer?!? +1 from me to compensate. Please do the same...

Answer (score 3):

You can also do a list comprehension:

```
>>> [chr(i) for i in range(97,97+26)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternate way to implement this. I am new to Python and I had not yet learned what a list comprehension is, so this helped me understand both list comprehensions and the answer to my original question, but I accepted the other one as my answer because it is simpler to maintain and to understand, but thank you still! :)

Comment: @ArifAli: Actually, you choose the right answer as 'the answer' for this. You should use `ascii_lowercase` in preference to generating these constants. I just showed this as an alternative. Glad it was of educational value to you!