# Data type validation in python - Strings

Tags: python, validation

I am currently writing some python code that asks for a users name. I need the program to validate whether the user's input is a string or not. If it is a string, The loop will break and the programme will continue. If the input is not a string (like a float, integer etc), It will loop around and ask the user to input a valid string. I understand that you can use the following code when you are checking for an integer;

```
while True:
try:
    number = int(input("Plese enter a number: "))
    break
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid integer")
```

I was thinking that I could use something like this to check for a string;

```
while True:
try:
    word = str(input("Plese enter a string: "))
    break
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid string")
```

But as far as I understand, the **str()** just converts the user's input to a string, regardless of the data that was entered.

Please help!

thanks

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do. What's a valid string to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if type of a variable is string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string)

Comment: So, I want the programme to check whether the user has typed in a string. If so, it will break the loop as shown in the code. If the user has entered another type of data (integer, float etc), It will tell them to try again.

Comment: It's *always* a string. Even if they type `487`, you'll get a string.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if the user entered only alphabetic characters (no numeric or special characters)?

Comment: @MrMas . Yes. I only want alphabetic characters (:

Comment: This post may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060899/alphabet-range-python of course it doesn't deal with anything but the English alphabet.

Comment: This may have helped me @MrMas , I'm going to try something a bit different, will let you know if it works (:

Comment: The problem has been solved by @OzgurVatansever , But thanks for the help (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it looks like you want to check if the input consists of alphabetic characters only. You can use [`.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method:

```
while True:
    word = input("Please enter a string: ")
    if word.isalpha():
        # Do something with valid input.
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid string")
```