# Validating Specific DataType PYTHON

Tags: python

I am trying to validate the user input to check if it is a string or number.If it is a number I want to say 'Please input letters'
This is the code i tried out

```
while True:
    try:
        member = str(input('Are you a child or adult member? '))
    except TypeError:
        print('Please input letters')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data type validation in python - Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011545/data-type-validation-in-python-strings)

Comment: Digits are just as valid in strings as letters, so there's no way you're going to get a `TypeError` here. If you want to check the contents of a string, there are lots of methods on the string type that you can see with `help(str)` in the interactive interpreter or the documentation, including things like `isalpha` and `isdigit`.

Comment: You just need `int()` instead of `str()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, the `input()` function always returns a string, even if the string entirely consists of digits, it still returns it as a string, e.g: `"123"`.

So, trying to catch an error when converting it to a string will never work as it is always already a string!

The correct way to do this would be to use `.isdigit()` to check if it is an integer.

```
while True:
    member = input('Are you a child or adult member? ');
    if member.isdigit():
        print('Please input letters')
    else:
        break
```

---

However, if you want to validate properly, you should not allow the user to enter any string, you should restrict them to `"child"` or `"adult"`:

```
while True:
    member = input('Are you a child or adult member? ');
    if member not in ('child', 'adult'):
        print('Please enter a valid entry.')
    else:
        break
```