# The convenient way to slice continuous columns based on elements from pandas?

Tags: pandas

### Raw columns look like this:

```
df.columns = ['a','b','c',...,'z']
```

there are 26 columns in a dataframe where starting 'a' element to 'z' one.

### Output:

I want continuous columns where the start is 'd' and the end is 'v'.

```
new_cols = ['d','e',...,'v']
```

### Trying:

```
df.loc[:,'d':'v'].columns
```

### Hope:

I don't what the method about dataframe(like `df.loc`) but columns(like `df.columns`) which I could not find it.

Comment: Are you after being able to slice the `df.columns` or getting your `df` with the rows but only those columns in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) or [`Index.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html) for positions of columns:

Also is added `max` function for avoiding error if select last column `z`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(26)], columns=L)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j ...   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 ...  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25



print (df.columns[df.columns.get_loc('d'): max(df.columns.get_loc('v') + 1, len(df.index))])

Index(['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
       'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v'],
      dtype='object')
```

Alternatively:

```
print (df.columns[df.columns.searchsorted('d'): 
                  max(df.columns.searchsorted('v') + 1, len(df.index))])

Index(['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
       'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v'],
      dtype='object')
```

Thank you [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571749/the-convenient-way-to-slice-continuous-colunms-based-on-elements-from-pandas/45571878?noredirect=1#comment78103468_45571878) for another solution:

```
print (df.columns.to_series()['d':'v'].values)
['d' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u'
 'v']
```

Comment: Or maybe `df.columns.to_series()['d':'v'].values`

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060899/alphabet-range-python) answer was helpful.

If `df`is your original a-z dataframe, do this:

```
import string
df[list(string.ascii_lowercase)[3:22]]
```

That will slice it the way you want it sliced.