# Pandas dataframe replace unique values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
col1  col2  col3
Aba   xxx   yyy
bab   bhh   jjj
ccc   kkk   lll
Aba   xxx   yyy
ccc   kkk   jjj
```

I want to replace unique values of each column with something like:
In `col1`: `Aba` gets replaced with `a0`,`bab` gets replaced with `a1`, `ccc` gets replaced with `a2` whereever it appears in the column.

Similarly with `col2`: `xxx` gets replaced with `b0`,`bhh` gets replaced with `b1` etc.

In short first column starts replacing unique values with `a0,a1,a2,a3` 2nd one with `b0,b1,b2,b3`, third column with `c0,c1,c2`.. etc .

Looking for a solution in loop so that I can process all the columns and all the unique values all together coz I have more than a million rows.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [184]: ['a','b','c'] + df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(str)
Out[184]:
  col1 col2 col3
0   a0   b0   c0
1   a1   b1   c1
2   a2   b2   c2
3   a0   b0   c0
4   a2   b2   c1
```

a bit more generic approach:

```
import string

c = list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:len(df.columns)]
df1 = c + df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(str)
df1
  col1 col2 col3
0   a0   b0   c0
1   a1   b1   c1
2   a2   b2   c2
3   a0   b0   c0
4   a2   b2   c1
```

Comment: @jezrael, thank you! I didn't get it - what "bar" do you mean?

Comment: I modify answer for remove it ;)

Comment: @MaxU - The best and the smartest solution! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @jezrael, ah, i got it now - you were talking about iPython prompt... Thanks for editing the answer !:-)

Comment: @user1111, glad i could help! :-)

Comment: No, I think html bar if long line in answer ;)

Comment: @user1111, while this solution is very good, I'm not convinced it's the best, certainly not from an efficiency perspective (using `apply` to loop columns). I've added another solution so at least you can compare.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `numpy` solution. It should be efficient as list comprehension often faster than `apply` + `lambda`.

Source for alphabet range: [Alphabet range python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060899/alphabet-range-python)

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'Aba', 1: 'bab', 2: 'ccc', 3: 'Aba', 4: 'ccc'},
                   'col2': {0: 'xxx', 1: 'bhh', 2: 'kkk', 3: 'xxx', 4: 'kkk'},
                   'col3': {0: 'yyy', 1: 'jjj', 2: 'lll', 3: 'yyy', 4: 'jjj'}})

a = df.values
f = np.array([np.unique(a[:, i], return_inverse=True)[1] for i in range(a.shape[1])]).T

res = list(ascii_lowercase[:a.shape[1]]) + \
      pd.DataFrame(f.astype(str), columns=df.columns)

#   col1 col2 col3
# 0   a0   b2   c2
# 1   a1   b0   c0
# 2   a2   b1   c1
# 3   a0   b2   c2
# 4   a2   b1   c0
```

Comment: It gives an error `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please see update for complete code.

Comment: It gives `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`  if any of the value in the row is 0.

Comment: With `pandas`, you should not use mixed types if possible. Convert your columns to strings via `df[col] = df[col].astype(str)` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply anyway. The previous solution from @MaxU
worked perfect for my set of data in one line.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to reiterate that "best answer" is subjective. Many 1-line answers in Python are sub-optimal.