# Keep Getting 'None' Result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing an assignment for class, where we're supposed to:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter a 10-character telephone number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX. The application should display the telephone number with any alphabetic characters that appeared in the original translated to their numeric equivalent.  For example, if the user enters 555-GET-FOOD, the application should display 555-438-3663. Use  a  loop  to  iterate  over  each  character  in  the  string.   Write  a  function  that  converts  a  letter  to the correct number according to the mapping listed above.  Call this function in the loop to convert the characters.

This is the code I have so far:

```
# write function that converts letter to number
def num_trans(number):
    num = number.upper()
    if char == "A" or char == "B" or char == "C":
        num.replace(char,"2")
    elif char == "D" or char == "E" or char == "F":
        num.replace(char,"3")
    elif char == "G" or char == "H" or char == "I":
        num.replace(char,"4")
    elif char == "J" or char == "K" or char == "L":
        num.replace(char,"5")
    elif char == "M" or char == "N" or char == "O":
        num.replace(char,"6")
    elif char == "P" or char == "Q" or char == "R" or char == "S":
        num.replace(char,"7")
    elif char == "T" or char == "U" or char == "V":
        num.replace(char,"8")
    elif char == "W" or char == "X" or char == "Y" or char == "Z":
        num.replace(char,"9")
# ask for user input phone number
numb = input("Please input a number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ")
# change letters to numbers
    # use loop to go over each character
for char in numb:
    new_num = num_trans(numb)
# print number
print(new_num)
```

Anything I enter in the input, I just get "None". I have no idea how to fix this. Please help

Comment: Your `num_trans` function doesn't return anything. Do you want to be replacing the `number` argument with the result of the `replace` call? Your code is pretty confusing, the function should probably take `char` as an argument too, rather than using it as a global variable.

Comment: You need to return a value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.6 - How to translate a telephone number with words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417352/python-3-6-how-to-translate-a-telephone-number-with-words)

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function returns None without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053652/function-returns-none-without-return-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things you may need to know:

1. strings are immutable, `replace()` does not change the strings in-place, which means if you don't save your result in a new variable, you just get the original one.
2. after you save the new result, you need to `return` it, so the variable outside can assign its value, otherwise the function just return `None`.
3. although your code can run, having a variable (`char` in this case) that is not defined in function parameter is really confusing.

I make only small changes of your code to make it works, but it can be further improved:

```
def num_trans(number):
    num = number.upper()
    if char == "A" or char == "B" or char == "C":
        # save result after replace
        num = num.replace(char,"2")
    elif char == "D" or char == "E" or char == "F":
        num =  num.replace(char,"3")
    elif char == "G" or char == "H" or char == "I":
        num = num.replace(char,"4")
    elif char == "J" or char == "K" or char == "L":
        num = num.replace(char,"5")
    elif char == "M" or char == "N" or char == "O":
        num = num.replace(char,"6")
    elif char == "P" or char == "Q" or char == "R" or char == "S":
        num = num.replace(char,"7")
    elif char == "T" or char == "U" or char == "V":
        num = num.replace(char,"8")
    elif char == "W" or char == "X" or char == "Y" or char == "Z":
        num = num.replace(char,"9")
    # return it
    return num
numb = input("Please input a number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX: ")
new_num = numb
for char in numb:
    # use num_trans(new_num) to replace the string recursively
    # otherwise num_trans(numb) only do the last change
    new_num = num_trans(new_num)
print(new_num)
```

Output:

```
555-438-3663
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def num_trans(number):
    num = number.upper()
    if num == "A" or num == "B" or num == "C":
        return '2'
    elif num == "D" or num == "E" or num == "F":
        return '3'
    elif num == "G" or num == "H" or num == "I":
        return '4'
    elif num == "J" or num == "K" or num == "L":
        return '5'
    elif num == "M" or num == "N" or num == "O":
        return '6'
    elif num == "P" or num == "Q" or num == "R" or num == "S":
        return '7'
    elif num == "T" or num == "U" or num == "V":
        return '8'
    elif num == "W" or num == "X" or num == "Y" or num == "Z":
        return '9'
    else:
        return str(num)

def new_function():
    new_number = ''
    for char in '555-GET-FOOD':
        new_number += num_trans(char)
    print(new_number)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_function()
```

output

```
555-438-3663
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do more of what you are trying to achieve by returning a value from `num_trans`:

```
def num_trans(number):
    num = number.upper()
    if char == "A" or char == "B" or char == "C":
        return "2"
    elif char == "D" or char == "E" or char == "F":
        return "3"
    elif char == "G" or char == "H" or char == "I":
        return "4"
```

and so on - **but** you will also need to reassemble these values as they come back from the function, and handle other characters like numbers and dashes.