# convert alphabet string to list

Tags: python, string, list, alphabet

so I read this: [Alphabet range in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060899/alphabet-range-in-python)

And I have a question and since I can't comment (reputation) I do it like this. On of the awnsers is that you can make a list of a string consisting of all letters doing this: `list(string.ascii_lowercase)`,
but when I do that it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
```

When only typing `string.ascii_lowercase` or `string.ascii_letter` or `string.digits` it does give me a string of what I want, but I want it in a list form...
I have of course imported string, (import string). So I also want a list consisting of letters and 1 consisting of digits and due to this error, I can't get that done. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `print(list)`. You have assigned something to `list` variable when you shouldn't.

Comment: type `del list` and try it will work. The reason is explained by @Austin