# In python, I'm trying to create a list of letters(a,b,c,d...aa,ab,ac...) but I'm not sure how to do this, do you know how to do this?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a long list of strings of letters, then add .com to the end of them, so I can ping each website, then add working ones to a list of websites as a sort of web scraping project, but I just don't know how to create the list of websites, so I am trying to make a list like (a,b,c,d,e...aa,ab,ac,ad), which will all be pinged to check if it responds.

Comment: You can iterate over character codes, then use `chr()` to convert them to characters.

Comment: Or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060899/alphabet-range-in-python for how to get a string with all the letters, you can iterate over that. You can also use `itertools.combinations()` to create all the combinations.

Comment: A successful ping to a host is not a guarantee that there's a web server on that host and, conversely, not being able to ping a host is not a guarantee that there's not a web server on that host afaik.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a structure like the one in your example, you can use combinations from iter tools.

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_all_combinations(letters: str, max_len: int) -> tuple:
    """Creates all combinations of letters until a maximum length.
    Args:
        letters (str): string with the letters to combine. I.e. "abcde"
        max_len (int): maximum number of characters for the combinations.

    Returns:
        tuple: strings with the combinations.
    """
    all_combinations = []
    for i_len in range(1, max_len + 1):
        i_len_combinations = combinations(letters, i_len)
        all_combinations.extend(["".join(i) for i in i_len_combinations])
    return tuple(all_combinations)


letters = "abcde"
max_len = 3
print(get_all_combinations(letters, max_len))
```

And like [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698027/in-python-im-trying-to-create-a-list-of-lettersa-b-c-d-aa-ab-ac-but-im/71699293#comment126711739_71698027) said, you can use the link for [how to get a string with all the letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060899/alphabet-range-in-python) as a reference for the `letters` to be used.

For instance:

```
import string


print(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

But if you need also the permutations, you can change the import for the permutation function in itertools.

All combinations for "ab" are:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc')
```

But all the permutations are:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb')
```