# How to get a letter range in reversed order in Python?

Tags: python, list, range, alphabetical

I do realize this has already been addressed here (e.g., [Is it possible to make a letter range in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927114/is-it-possible-to-make-a-letter-range-in-python)). Nevertheless, I hope this question was different.

The below code gives the range between any two alphabets

```
[chr(i) for i in range(ord('H'),ord('P'))]
```

**Output**

```
['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
```

For the range of alphabets in reversed order, using `reversed()` returns the empty list

```
[chr(i) for i in range(ord('P'),ord('H'))]

# or 

[chr(i) for i in reversed(range(ord('P'),ord('H')))]
```

**Output**

```
[]
```

**Expected output**

```
['O', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'I', 'H']
```

How to get a letter range in reversed order in Python?

Comment: Your second example (`[chr(i) for i in reversed(range(ord('P'),ord('H')))]`) will fail for the same reason your first one did - you're still telling it to count from P to H. I think you intended to count from H to P and then reverse it.

Comment: I want to count from `P` to `H`

Comment: Correct, and you can do that by counting from H to P and then reversing it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ord('P')` is greater than `ord('H')`, so `range(...)` makes an empty range.

To get a reverse letter list, do *either* of the following:

- Make a forward list and apply `reverse()`:

  ```
  reversed( range(ord('H'), ord('P')) )
  ```
- Use the 3rd parameter to `range()`:

  ```
  range(ord('P'), ord('H'), -1)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
ord('P') -> 80
ord('H') -> 72
```

so  `[chr(i) for i in range(ord('P'),ord('H'))]` is simply `[chr(i) for i in range(80,72)]` and in `range` defualt increment value is 1.

since start value > end value and default step increment is 1, so this iterator is running resulting in an empty list.

you need to change the increment value from default to -1

`[chr(i) for i in range(ord('P')-1,ord('H')-1,-1)]`

output

```
['O', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'I', 'H']
```