# Better way to concatenate many columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 30 columns. 26 of the column names are the names of the alphabet letters. I'd like to take those 26 columns and make them into one column as one string.

```
price  dateCreate  volume  country  A  B  C  D  E ..... Z
19     20190501    25      US       1  2  5  6  19      30
49     20190502    30      US       5  4  5  0  34      50
```

I want this:

```
price  dateCreate  volume  country  new_col
19     20190501    25      US       "1,2,5,6,19,....30"
49     20190502    30      US       "5,4,5,0,34,50"
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", concat($"A", $"B", ...$"Z"))
```

However, in the future when faced with this problem I'd like to know how I can more easily concatenate many columns. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply the following to any number of columns you want to concatenate

```
val df= Seq((19,20190501,24, "US",  1 , 2,  5,  6,  19 ),(49,20190502,30, "US", 5 , 4,  5,  0,  34 )).
        toDF("price", "dataCreate", "volume", "country", "A","B","C","D","E")

val exprs = df.columns.drop(4).map(col _)

df.select($"price", $"dataCreate", $"volume", $"country", concat_ws(",", 
         array(exprs: _*)).as("new_col"))


+-----+----------+------+-------+----------+
|price|dataCreate|volume|country|   new_col|
+-----+----------+------+-------+----------+
|   19|  20190501|    24|     US|1,2,5,6,19|
|   49|  20190502|    30|     US|5,4,5,0,34|
+-----+----------+------+-------+----------+
```

for completeness, here is the pyspark equivalent

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df= spark.createDataFrame([[19,20190501,24, "US",  1 , 2,  5,  6,  19 ],[49,20190502,30, "US", 5 , 4,  5,  0,  34 ]],
        ["price", "dataCreate", "volume", "country", "A","B","C","D","E"])

exprs = [col for col in df.columns[4:]]

df.select("price","dataCreate", "volume", "country", F.concat_ws(",",F.array(*exprs)).alias("new_col"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you had something similar to the next one in mind:

**Scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat_ws}

val cols = ('A' to 'Z').map{col(_)}

df.withColumn("new_col", concat_ws(",", cols:_*)
```

**Python**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws
import string

cols = [col(x) for x in string.ascii_uppercase]

df.withColumn("new_col", concat_ws(",", *cols))
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, if this was pyspark how would you write this?

Comment: @user2896120, For scala/pyspark refer this answer..!https://stackoverflow.com/a/57098840/7632695

Comment: You can take the a-z list as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190122/python-how-to-print-range-a-z. Then use the a-z list as [col(x) for x in a_zlist]

Answer (score 2):

From Spark 2.3.0, you can use concatenation operator directly to do this in *spark-sql* itself.

```
spark.sql("select A||B||C from table");
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19951