# Is there any way i can loop through a-z instead of writing multiple for loop stataments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

So im trying to do a charachter count on a given list.

`a = ["farshad", "ghassemi?d", "madam", "?radar?", "duration", "con?tained"]`

my expected output is:

> farshad contains 2 a

And this goes on .....

My code is:

```py
def charCount():
    a = ["farshad", "ghassemi?d", "madam", "?radar?", "duration", "con?tained"]

    for word in a:
        for letter in word:
            x = word.count("a")
        print(word, "contains", x, "a")

    for word in a:
        for letter in word:
            x = word.count("d")
        print(word, "contains", x, "d")

charCount()
```

Im trying to do this all in one for loop, for example A-Z ....

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: why do you need the inner for loop? `.count()` iterates over the letters in a word already.

Comment: you want to change the `print` to be in the inner `for` loop and change it to `x = word.count(letter)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190122/python-how-to-print-range-a-z

Comment: Vandalizing your own questions is not allowed here.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 2 for loops. (I assume the question means 1 separate for loops and allows nested for loops) This is how I did it:

```py
import string

def charCount():
    a = ["farshad", "ghassemi?d", "madam", "?radar?", "duration", "con?tained"]

    for word in a:
        for i in string.ascii_lowercase:
            x = word.lower().count(i)
            print(word, "contains", x, i)

charCount()
```

All you need to do is loop through every character. `string.ascii_lowercase` contains every single lowercase letter, so I used that. Then, we get the count of i in `word.lower()`. `word.lower()` turns the word into lowercase making it count for capitals as well.

If you wanted to shorten it further, you could change the inner for loop like this:

```py
def charCount():
    a = ["farshad", "ghassemi?d", "madam", "?radar?", "duration", "con?tained"]

    for word in a:
        for i in string.ascii_lowercase: print(word, "contains", word.lower().count(i), i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome! As a general rule here on stackoverflow, if an answer has helped you, then please remember to accept a correct answer and upvote it if it was helpful. (This does not apply to my answer, but any answer here.) Please visit stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Answering questions helps improve the site. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to go through the whole alphabet for each word? Or just the letters in those words?

If you're only wanting to count the letters in each word you can try:

```
def charCount():

    a = ["farshad", "ghassemi?d", "madam", "?radar?", "duration", "con?tained"]

    for word in a:

        word_set = set(word)

        for letter in word_set:
            x = word.count(letter)
            print(word, "contains", x, letter)
```

This will create a `set` for each word, which will prevent duplicate letters from being printed.

If you're wanting to ignore those question marks, you could put this inside the inner loop:

```
            if letter == '?':
                continue
```

Bear in mind this solution won't order your letters in any particular order as sets are inherently unordered.

Comment: Thank u very much !

Answer (score 0):

## my answer

```
def charCount(search_letter):
    a = ["farshad", "ghassemi?d", "madam", "?radar?", "duration", "con?tained"]
    for word in a:
        word = word.lower()
        for letter in word:
            x = word.count(search_letter)
            print(word, "contains", x, search_letter)
# letters = ("aeiou")
letters = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")    
for search_letter in letters:
    charCount(search_letter)
```

Comment: You could add word.lower() if you are going to have uppercase letters in your list.

Comment: Also, the search word "letters"! could be adjusted to contain the letters you want to search for in each word of the list of words e.g. if you only wanted to search for Vowles then letters would be "aeiou"